# If a REST request can take 10 minutes

Tags: php, rest, azure

I'm about to implement a REST server (in ASP.NET although I think that's irrelevant here). where what I want to do is the request is made and it returns the result. However, this result is an .XLSX file that could be a million rows.

If I'm generating a million row spreadsheet, it's going to take about 10 minutes. An http request will time out. So what's the best way to handle this delay in the result.

Second, what's the best way to return a very large file as the REST result?

**Update:** The most common use case is the REST server is an Azure cloud service web worker (basically IIS on Azure). The client is a PHP web app running on a different server in a different location. The PHP web app needs to send up a report template (generally 25K) and the data which can be a connection string to a SQL database, or... could be a 500M XML file. So that is the request, an XML file containing the template and datasource(s).

The response if a file - PDF, DOCX, XLSX, PPTX, or HTML. That can be a BLOB inside an XML file or it can be the file itself. In the case of an error then it must return XML with the error information. The big issue is it can take 10 minutes to generate this file if everything goes right. When it's a 1 million row spreadsheet, it takes time to pull down all that data and populate the created XLSX file. Second issue, this is then a really large file.

So even if everything is perfect, there's a big delay and a large response.

Comment: I don't think you should think of doing it that way. Just return the url to the file and use the url in your code. Its not just for rest, I don't think any web "application" should be serving files.

Comment: Timeouts in the context of HTTP can come from any number of places, in the client, server, or gateways in between, for a number of reasons, from delays in connection, response or delays between chunks of response data, or even 'total request time.'  which of these timeouts you need to manage, if any, depends on the stack you're working with.  Please tell us more about the http clients you expect to use in your scenario...

Comment: @IfLoop I updated it - let me know what else you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

- Write file to response stream during its generation (from client side this looks like downloading large file);
- Start file generation task on server side and return task id immediatly. Add API methods, that allows retreive task status, cancel it or get results (if task completed).

Comment: I like your option #2 (I didn't think of that). I'm going to play around with that.

Comment: Is there any way to alert the client app when it's ready? I don't think so, but I figure better to ask.

Comment: Is there any way to alert the client app when it's ready? Yes it is, you have at least three options: polling (roughly speaking, client send ajax-requests to server each N seconds until task is completed/cancelled), server sent events (technology based on keeped-alive stream used to send commands only from server to client !!not supported in IE!!), web sockets (fast full duplex client-server communication, supported by all modern browsers).

Answer (score 0):

interesting question,
i sure hope you have a stable connection, anyway, at the client side, in this case, php, set the timeouts to very high values. in php
set_time_limit(3600*10);
curl_setopt($curlh,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,3600*10);